# Move ngClass code from the HTML into Typescript Function

Tags: angular

Hoping someone can help. I'm new to Angular and have just started to learn how to apply conditional classes. I have a table that has a status column, and I want to add a class depending on what the status is e.g. If it is a status of Active, I want that `<td>` to have an 'active' class.

I have got it working by adding the following into my HTML:

```
<td class="" [ngClass]="{ 'active': this.sysuser.status === 'Active', 'pending': this.sysuser.status === 'Pending Setup' }">{{sysuser.status}}</td>
```

But what I'd prefer is to wrap it in a function in my .ts file, so it'd be something like:

```
<td class="first_of_group center date" [ngClass]="setStatusClass()">{{sysuser.status}}</td>
```

Then in my .ts file:

```
setStatusClass(){
   // insert required code here
}
```

Hoping someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getter as:

```
get StatusClass() {
    let class = '';
    switch(this.sysuser.status) {
        case 'Active':
            class = 'active';
            break;
        case 'Pending Setup':
            class = 'pending';
            break;
    }
    return class;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td class="first_of_group center date" [ngClass]="StatusClass">{{sysuser.status}}</td>
```

Comment: In above solution, if you update `sysuser` it will automatically render new class as I made a `getter` for it.

Comment: You can accept/upvote the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.......

```
<td class="" [ngClass]="setStatusClass(sysuser.status)">{{sysuser.status}}</td>
```

Function

```
setStatusClass(status) {
    switch (status) {
      case 'Active':
        return 'active';
      case 'Pending Setup':
        return 'pending';
    }
  }
```